# how to pass vector objects from one class to another

Tags: c++

This is how I had tried sending the vector using one of the answers I got., but has not worked out yet.Should copy whn it gets to auctioneer.I want to display.

```
class Trader {   
private:   
        int nextBidId; 

public:   

        void loadRange( vector <Bid> & bids ) {} ;

class Simulator //Receives from the Trader,doent modify 
{ 
    vector <Bid> bids;
    Trader trader; 
    Auctioneer auctioneer; 

public: 
    void run(); 
}; 

void Simulator::run() { 
    trader.loadRange(vector<Bid> & bids);
    auctioneer.accept_bids(bid_vector::const_iterator begin, bid_vector::const_iterator end);
    auctioneer.displayBids();
} 

class Auctioneer // Has to receive from the simulator class 
{ 

public: 
    vector <Bid> bids,v2;
    void accept_bids(vector<Bid> & bids);
    void displayBids(){cout << "\tBid\t(" <<  setw(3) << bids.bidId << "\t " << setw(3) << bids.trdId  << "\t "  
                                          << setw(3) <<  bids.type <<"\t " << setw(3) << bids.qty <<"\t "  << setw(3) 
                                          << bids.price <<")\t\n "  ;    }
};
```

**UPDATE**

I have just copied a vector from another class, am now trying to see its contednts.its returning an error:

Error: - begin has not been declared.how do I decalre bigin for the vector?

```
void Auctioneer::accept_bids(const BidList& bid){ 
    vector<Auctioneer> *list;
    vector<Auctioneer>::iterator itr; // create an iterator

     for ( itr = list.begin();
     itr != list.end(); ++itr )
     cout << *itr << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Post some code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: That is far more code than necessary to illustrate things. You need to make some effort to reduce the code enough to just show the essence of the problem.

Comment: Well you can just use a simple illustration ignoring the code,how would you pass a vector of bids from class A to class B and then Class B passes it on to Class C. B being the mediator.

Comment: I moved your update from an answer up to the question as clarification. Your problem is you are declaring list as a pointer to a vector. Get rid of the star (*) on that line and you'll be on the way. Also, you will get a benefit out of using a typedef for vector<Auctioneer> instead of having to repeat yourself. Also, do you really want a vector of Auctioneer, or do you really want vector<Bid> (and pass in vector<Bid>::iterator).

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Just pass a copy of the vector**

Simply pass the vector into a function in class B (e.g. `B::accept_bids(const bid_vector& bids)`, or perhaps using iterators `B::accept_bids(bid_vector::const_iterator begin, bid_vector::const_iterator end)`), and have that function copy the vector into a private data member with the assignment operator (or `std::copy()` if you use iterators). This is the simplest and most straightforward solution.

**Option 2: Your vector is large, and the costs (allocation time, copy time, memory use) of copying it are high**

Pass the vector as above, but instead of taking a copy of the vector, store the reference (or the iterators) and ensure that class A's copy of the original vector does not go away or change after it has been passed to class B.

Alternately, pass it using `std::auto_ptr` and make it clear (with a function name such as `give_bid_vector(std::auto_ptr<bid_vector> bids)`) that class B is taking ownership of the vector. This means class A is no longer the owner of the vector and should not delete it.

Comment: An advantage of passing by iterators is you can copy with a predicate only bids that the second class is interested in, or you can process the vector in a lazy fashion in cases when you might not need to process it all.

Comment: If you are passing using references, you are not passing a copy.

Comment: You're right, but I can't find where I said that. Option 1 is about B taking a copy, Option 2 is about B sharing the vector with A.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is the bit of code you are talking about:

```
{
    trader.loadRange(bidlist, NUMBIDS); 
    auctioneer.receiveBids(bidlist, NUMBIDS);
    auctioneer.displayBids(string ss){return str;}
}
```

In which case you need to make the three functions look something like this:

```
class Trader {
   ...
   void loadRange( vector <Bid> & bids ) {
      // do stuff with bids
   }
};
```

the other functions look the same. Then modify the calling code:

```
{
    vector <Bid> bidList;
    trader.loadRange(bidlist ); 
    auctioneer.receiveBids(bidlist);
    auctioneer.displayBids(string ss){return str;}
}
```

Note there is no need to pass the size around - vectors have their own size() member.

Comment: I tried it that  way too, got an error
 no match for 'operator=' in 'ss = ((Auctioneer*)this)->Auctioneer::bidList' 
[code]
vector <Bid> bidList; 
   void receiveBids(string ss){ss = bidList;};
   void displayBids(){ cout << bid.bidId,.....  ; }
[/code]

Comment: thanks for the assistance, it worked out so well with solution 2